# Matching closest ancestor with Path Hierarchy Tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I've got an Elasticsearch v5 index set up for mapping config hashes to URLs.

```
{
 "settings": {
   "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "url-analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "url-tokenizer"
        }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
        "url-tokenizer": {
            "type": "path_hierarchy",
            "delimiter": "/"
        }
    }
}
},
"mappings": {
    "route": {
      "properties": {
        "uri": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed",
            "analyzer": "url-analyzer"
        },
        "config": {
            "type": "object"
        }}}}}
```

I would like to match the longest path prefix with the highest score, so that given the documents

```
{ "uri": "/trousers/", "config": { "foo": 1 }}
{ "uri": "/trousers/grey", "config": { "foo": 2 }}
{ "uri": "/trousers/grey/lengthy", "config": { "foo": 3 }}
```

when I search for `/trousers`, the top result should be `trousers`, and when I search for `/trousers/grey/short` the top result should be `/trousers/grey`.

Instead, I'm finding that the top result for `/trousers` is `/trousers/grey/lengthy`.

How can I index and query my documents to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution, after drinking on it: what if we treat the URI in the index as a *keyword*, but still use the PathHierarchyTokenizer on the search input?

Now we store the following docs:

`/trousers`
`/trousers/grey`
`/trousers/grey/lengthy`

When we submit a query for `/trousers/grey/short`, the search_analyzer can build the input `[trousers, trousers/grey, trousers/grey/short]`.

The first two of our documents will match, and we can trivially select the longest match using a custom sort.

Now our mapping document looks like this:

```
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "uri-analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "uri-query": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "uri-tokenizer"
        }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
        "uri-tokenizer": {
            "type": "path_hierarchy",
            "delimiter": "/"
        }
    }
}},

"mappings": {
    "route": {
      "properties": {
        "uri": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,
            "analyzer": "uri-analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "uri-query"
        },

        "config": {
            "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```

and our query looks like this:

```
{
    "sort": {
            "_script": {
                    "script": "doc.uri.length",
                    "order": "asc",
                    "type": "number"
            }
    },
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "uri": {
                "query": "/trousers/grey/lengthy",
                "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
    }
}
```